# Абхаз или абхазец?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я всегда жителей Абхазии называла абхазцами. Но сейчас часто слышу вариант "абхаз". Мне интуитивно кажется, что это неверно — все равно что сказать "армян" вместо "армянин". Но, с другой стороны, мы говорим "осетин", а не "осетинец".
Все-таки как правильно называть эту национальность?

Answer (score 1):

> Все-таки как правильно называть эту национальность?

Правильно и **АБХАЗЦЫ**, и **АБХАЗЫ**.
[С. А. Ушакова "Словарь трудностей русского языка для школьников"](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Nop0WzCpvtEC&pg=PA7&dq=%22%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B7%22+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=9ussVYi7G8WhsAHMwYHwCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B7%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Да, корректно оба варианта: АБХА́ЗЫ, -ов и АБХА́ЗЦЫ, -ев, мн. (ед. абха́з, -а и абха́зец, -зца, м.; абха́зка, -и, мн. абха́зки, -зок, -зкам, ж.). Нация, коренное население Абхазской АССР, а также лица, относящиеся к этой нации.

[См. Словарь русского языка](http://feb-web.ru/feb/mas/mas-abc/01/ma102017.htm)

См. также словарь на Грамоте.ру.

Answer (score 0):

Примеры и ссылки очень хорошие и убедительные, но, посмотрите, что было в словаре *раньше*:

**АБХАЗЫ,**  -ов *мн*. ( ед. **абхаз,** -а, *м*.; **абхазка,**  -и, *мн*. абхазки,  -зок,  -зкам,  *ж*. ). Народ, составляющий основное население Абхазской АССР.
*Словарь русского языка в четырёх томах, томI, Москва, **1957**.*

Поистине, велик и *изменчив* ...